# When you come up for air, does it matter how long you stay up?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

When you come up from out of the water to get air so that you do not take damage, are you instantly able to stay underwater for the maximum amount of time before you start taking damage when you go back under water? Or do you have to stay above water for a certain amount of time?

Comment: Down-voting because this is trivially testable.

Comment: @Iszi I wouldn't consider that a valid reason for a downvote. This question falls perfectly into the bounds set by [the FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq). If a question is easy to answer, then you should answer it instead of bashing it.

Comment: @Koviko The down-vote tooltip gives, as the *first* reason for down-voting, "This question does not show any research effort...".  Why don't I answer it now?  'Cause I'm not in the mood to play Skyrim just now, and the desire to pursue an answer to this particular question isn't burning quite so much - especially when there are so many ways to gain Waterbreathing, or just plain avoid having to spend long amounts of time underwater until you *can* get Waterbreathing.  Therefore, the question also borderlines on "not useful" - another justification for down-vote, given in the tooltip.

Comment: @Iszi I found it hard to figure out since it seemed to just refill really quick, but I actually think it refills instantly like with casting/drinking for water breathing effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it does not matter, the bar instantly refills. It also will completely refill when casting a waterbreathing spell under water or taking a potion having that same effect. So just come up to the surface until the bar disappears and you're good to go back down.